# What does $\{0,1\}^n$ mean?

Tags: notation

Could you explain what the below text means? What does $\{0,1\}^n$ mean?

> the keys are chosen uniformly from the set of words of length of the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ denoted by $\{0,1\}^n$.

Comment: The set of all $n$-tuples over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$. In other words, the set of all binary strings of length $n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does X^k mean in mathematical logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955983/what-does-xk-mean-in-mathematical-logic)

Answer (score 1):

Set of words consisting of $0$ and $1$ of length $n$, e. g. $\{0,1\}^3=\{000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the set of ordered tuples $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ where each $x_i$ is $0$ or $1.$ This is an example of Cartesian product.